# I'm not sure if I need to manually 'clean up' my objects or if the garbage collector will take care of it

Tags: c#, .net

I've been researching [the IDispose interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx) however I'm struggling to understand what I need to do (if anything) to ensure my objects are 'taken care of' appropriately in certain instances.

I know that I should use `using` (i.e. the syntactic sugar for `Dispose()`) to make sure I am releasing unmanaged resources, however when I create a temporary object I am not sure if I need to do something to actively release it or if the garbage collector will take care of it the same way it would a temporary variable.

For example:-

```
public void LoadSerializedClass(string filePath) 
{ 
    Binary formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            MySerializedClass mySerializedClass 
                = (MySerializedClass)formatter.Deserialize(input); 

            /* ... use the deserialized class ... */ 

            /* ... the deserialized class is no longer needed... */
        } 
    }
}
```

- I use `using` to make sure the unmanaged resource is disposed of properly.
- (At the moment) I do not do anything to dispose of the (intended to be) temporary instance of my `MySerializedClass` - I (perhaps very mistakenly) thought it would behave as a local temporary variable would, and I would not need to manage it. Am I incorrect? I got the impression from the research I did that I would *not* have to do anything, and the garbage collector will automatically pick it up; however a colleague gave the impression otherwise and I am obviously struggling to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: If the class doesn't implement `IDisposable` then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Use `using` or `.Dispose()` on all objects that implement `IDisposable` and you are done. All other object references will be taken care of.

Comment: Okay... and I would only implement `IDisposable` if the class itself used unmanaged resources, right?

Comment: @crashmstr So is the object reference effectively locally scoped? How does it work in effect? Since the variable which holds the reference to the object ceases to exist, are there effectively no references to the object so the garbage collector will clean it up? Is that what happens? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Eilidh " implement IDisposable if the class itself used unmanaged resources" - Or holds references to managed resources that _also_ implement `IDisposable`

Comment: @Eilidh Once there is no reference to an object, it can be garbage collected. If you put that reference into a long lived `List`, then it would exist at least as long as the list. Point is, you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to Dispose of objects that implement IDisposable. Your variable is fine. Even with objects which implement IDisposable the GC will get rid of them at some point if you do not dispose them. Problem is that the unmanaged resources would not be released in the meantime and you can starve the operating system of that resource or cause other problems. For example if you open a file and don't close it the OS will think the file is in use and won't let the user delete it. The GC will eventually collect the managed object and release the file but that may take quite a long time if your program is not under memory pressure.

For more information on how the GC works you may want to check some article about it. Basically if the GC decides that it needs to free some memory it starts with all the variables that are in scope + all static fields and goes through all the objects they reference and then recursively all the way down. When it is done marking it just deletes the unmarked objects. This is called Mark and Sweep (there are different strategies for GC this is just one of them). The GC does not look for unused objects it looks for used objects and deletes the rest.

As for IDisposable a properly implemented IDisposable will have a Finalizer (syntax is like C++ destructor ~). If the GC sees an object with a Finalizer it makes a note to call it before deleting an object. Normally the finalizer will do what the Dispose method would and release the unmanaged object. However note that the GC is only concerned with memory used by the program so it does not care about file handles or network connections. Maybe the OS needs these resources but from the point of view of the GC everything is fine since there is enough memory and it does not feel like calling these finalizers. This is why we explicitly need to release (dispose) the unmanaged resources.

Comment: Thank you. How does the garbage collector 'know' to dispose of the object? Is it that the variable which holds the reference to it only exists locally, so when the variable 'disappears' there is no longer a reference to the object, and the garbage collector knows to clean it up?

Comment: Yes - as soon as the program goes out of scope of the variable, it's eligible for collection (or sooner, if the compiler has done some optimisation tricks).

Comment: @Eilidh That is quite big question. There is some good reading here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Eilidh if you implement the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) then the garbage collector calls your finalizer. That will ensure the item gets disposed even if `Dispose()` is not called.

Comment: How do you handle event subscriptions?

Comment: @Mgetz finalizers are called regardless of the Dispose pattern - it is a pattern, not a language feature.